# Right-align (pad left) index column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, stdout

Consider the following simple example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux", "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo", "fred", "plugh", "xyzzy", "thud"]})

print(df)
```

This prints:

```
$ python3 test.py
      text
0      foo
1      bar
2      baz
3      qux
4     quux
5    corge
6   grault
7   garply
8    waldo
9     fred
10   plugh
11   xyzzy
12    thud
```

Note that the autogenerated index column is printed left-aligned (padded with spaces to right).

How can I make the printout of the autogenerated index column  to be right-aligned (padded with spaces to left); that is:

```
      text
 0     foo
 1     bar
 2     baz
 3     qux
 4    quux
 5   corge
 6  grault
 7  garply
 8   waldo
 9    fred
10   plugh
11   xyzzy
12    thud
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.rjust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rjust.html):

```
s = df.index.astype(str)
df.index = s.str.rjust(s.str.len().max(), ' ')
```

*Note that the index is now a string, not a number.*

Output:

```
      text
 0     foo
 1     bar
 2     baz
 3     qux
 4    quux
 5   corge
 6  grault
 7  garply
 8   waldo
 9    fred
10   plugh
11   xyzzy
12    thud
```